# Why is R's implementation of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm so slow?

Tags: r, algorithm, gis

Plotting geographical polygons is not R's strength, but it can be very rewarding if [done well](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43534/how-to-create-an-attractive-choropleth-map-in-r). I'm using data from the UK and the detail in the polygon borders is ridiculously high, making any plotting or manipulation function (especially after fortify has been run to make it ggplot-able) slow.

The logical approach is to simplify the polygon geometries, so they are less complex.

I followed this [post](http://the-praise-of-insects.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/simplifying-polygon-shapefiles-in-r.html) to implement the Douglas-Peucker algorithm to do this in R, but it was painfully slow. Applied to [this dataset](http://ubuntuone.com/6k7MNBSy2ZK9nCtlq4Qp1z) (regions of England), the following code took ~10 minutes to run on my Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM machine with 16 Gb of RAM:

```
for(i in 1:length(gors@polygons)){
  for(j in 1:length(gors@polygons[[i]]@Polygons)){
    temp <- as.data.frame(gors@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[j]]@coords)
    names(temp) <- c("x", "y")
    temp2 <- dp(temp, 0.01)
    gors@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[j]]@coords <- as.matrix(cbind(temp2$x, temp2$y))
  }QGIS
}
```

In [QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/how-to-smooth-generalize-a-polygon-in-qgis), the same function took approximately one second.
Of course, I'll probably be using the QGIS implementation in the future, but just found it perplexing that the R implementation takes soooo long. Any ideas how to make it faster or implement the algorithm in a more efficient way greatly appreciated.

Comment: What plotting routines in `R` have you tried? I'm wondering if there might be a faster function to plot all your polygons, and what sort of plot times you're getting.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see where all the time is being spent? At a guess, you are doing a lot of calls to `[`, `[[`, `cbind`-ing objects and coercing to a matrix or data frame, plus dooing lots of assignment via `[[<-`. All that just eats compute time in R. I have no idea why QGIS is so fast, but it probably isn't running in interpreted code. I suspect to get close to that level of performance you'd need to move the algorithm to C (or more likely C++ employing the wonderful Rcpp package.)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've tried plot in sp and ggplot - latter is appallingly slow. Gavin, no, I've not profiled the code (and don't know how to!) and yes, I think QGIS core algorithms are deployed in C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I think you can use `rgeos` function `gSimplify` which interface [GEOS::simplify](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1simplify_1_1DouglasPeuckerLineSimplifier.html)

In the help file you'll have more information, for example this is the header

> Simplify Geometry
>
> Description:
>
> ```
>  Function simplifies the given geometry using the Douglas-Peuker
>  algorithm
> ```

Using your data something along this line should do this

```
require(rgeos)
require(rgdal)

gors <- readOGR(dsn = "/tmp/gor", layer = "GOR_st121")

system.time(gor_topo <- gSimplify(gors, tol = 0.01))
##  user  system elapsed 
## 0.713   0.010   0.727
```

I have an I7 but my spec are less impressive than yours so I expect this function to be faster when you'll try it.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks for that dickoa - usually things can be done in R as fast as other programs, and gSimplify proves this to be the case when it comes to simplifying complex polygons.

Comment: @RobinLovelace  as an aside, if you haven't installed the `sos` package, give it a whirl. It's the best tool I know for doing searches for functions and algorithms available in one `R` package or another.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks for the bonus tip. findFn("simplify geometry") would have done it, but my first attempt (simplify) generated too many results.